# One subscription for multiple routes

Tags: meteor, iron-router

If I have one subscription that will be used for multiple routes, should I call it each time in every controller's `waitOn` or is there a better place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to go:

#### subscribe on client startup

If your collection is small and used often then it could be beneficial to subscribe only once in `Meteor.startup` on client side.
That subscription won't be stopped when route is changed.

#### cache subscriptions

There is `Subscription Manager` which should allow to cache subscriptions, so subscriptions are not stopped every time route is changed.

https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager